# Cleft sentence: "is" vs "was"

Tags: tense

> It ***was / is*** in Paris that she was brought up.
>
> It ***was / is*** in this house that he lived.

Comment: It's actually kind of an interesting question... consider the sentence "This is the place where he lived"

Comment: @nicael: You may not like the usage, but most of the 80 written instances of [*It is here where he first*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+is+here+where+he+first%22) are followed by a ***past tense*** verb form. English isn't like computer languages or mathematical equations - it doesn't have to be (temporally or otherwise) consistent to the nth degree.

Comment: @Fumble Let me agree with you, I got the sentence slightly differently.

Answer (score 3):

Both of you sentences are placed in the past

> she *was* brought up
>   that he *lived*

so using "was" would be correct.

You may be getting confused since, for example, a tour guide might say

> It *is* in this house, that he spent his early years.

since they may be trying to emphasize the location, it is understandable, acceptable, and does get used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, that's why I gave the example using "is" which might be confusing to an ELL since they would probably have been taught to use the past tense. I wouldn't say using "is" is the "most common usage" either, only that it does happen. There are a lot of gotchas in English which an ELL'er could get confused by.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply *It **is** here that X **happened*** is a "common" usage - my guess is that *It **was** here...* would be far more common. I'm just saying that neither tense is inherently either correct or incorrect, so it's misleading to characterize one as being *not **as** correct* as the other. Purely speculation, but I suspect using ***is*** is more likely if the speaker & audience are *literally* at the relevant location (as opposed to "here" figuratively referencing whatever is currently being spoken of).

Comment: Correct, that's why I said used by a tour guide. I was meaning "not as correct" since formally in school one would be taught to use the past tense.

Comment: It is/was in this house both emphasize the location, so what's the difference?

Comment: @V.V.: The difference is that present tense emphasizes the "here and now" attribute of the location (i.e. - the referent is *right here, **as I speak**, in **this** place*).